# Number of format specifications in 'msgid' and 'msgstr' does not match msgfmt: found 1 fatal error

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

Django-Admin generates the following error: Execution of msgfmt failed: /home/djuka/project_app/locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/django.po:49: number of format specifications in 'msgid' and 'msgstr' does not match
msgfmt: found 1 fatal error
CommandError: compilemessages generated one or more errors.

I have the same number of strings in msgid and msgstr and i still get an error. Here is the code.

```
#: reBankMini/templates/reBankMiniApp/index.html:135
#, python-format
msgid ""
"Leta 2020 je po svetu nastalo rekordnih 54 milijonov ton elektronskih "
"odpadkov, kar je 21 odstotkov več kot v zadnjih petih letih. E-odpadki so "
"najhitreje rastoči gospodinjski odpadki na svetu, ki jih povzročajo predvsem "
"višje stopnje porabe električne in elektronske opreme, kratki življenjski "
"cikli in malo možnosti za popravila. Le 17,4%% zavrženih e-odpadkov leta "
"2020 je bilo recikliranih. Pri procesu recikliranju pride do številnih "
"okolju nevarnih reakcij. Mi recikliramo drugače. Prizadevamo si za varne, "
"trajnostne in popravljive izdelke, s katerimi bo vsak uporabnik aktivno "
"vključen v reševanje okoljskih problemov."

msgstr ""
"In 2020, a record 54 million tons of electronic "
"waste was generated worldwide, which is 21 percent more than in the last five years. E-waste is "
"the fastest growing household waste in the world, caused mainly by "
"higher levels of consumption of electrical and electronic equipment, short life "
"cycles and little opportunity for repair. Only 17.4% of e-waste discarded in "
"2020 was recycled. Many environmentally hazardous reactions occur "
"during the recycling process. We recycle differently. We strive for safe, "
"sustainable and repairable products that will actively involve every user "
"in solving environmental problems."
```

Here is the index.html file

```
<div class="rebank-desc">
        <h3>
            {% trans 'Leta 2020 je po svetu nastalo rekordnih 54 milijonov ton elektronskih odpadkov, kar je 21 odstotkov več kot v zadnjih petih letih. E-odpadki so najhitreje rastoči gospodinjski odpadki na svetu, ki jih povzročajo predvsem višje stopnje porabe električne in elektronske opreme, kratki življenjski cikli in malo možnosti za popravila. Le 17,4% zavrženih e-odpadkov leta 2020 je bilo recikliranih. Pri procesu recikliranju pride do številnih okolju nevarnih reakcij. Mi recikliramo drugače. Prizadevamo si za varne, trajnostne in popravljive izdelke, s katerimi bo vsak uporabnik aktivno vključen v reševanje okoljskih problemov.' %}
        </h3>
        <h3>
            {% trans 'Predstavljamo vam RebankMini, prvi power bank (prenosna baterija) na svetu, ki ga poganjajo reciklirane baterijske celice. rEbankMini je v celoti izdelan v Sloveniji in s tem prvi power bank izdelan v Evropi. Sestavljen je iz prestižnega slovenskega lesa, hrasta in oreha. Z nakupom enega rEbankMini-ja nam pomagate zmanjšati izpust toplogrednih plinov za 14,6 kg (CO2eq), ki bi nastali pri proizvodnji izdelka, podobnega našemu.' %}
        </h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but I would make a `msg` class in you app's `models.py` file. Also, are you trying to make the `msgid` a translated version of english? If so, making a `msg` class in your `models.py` file would provide you with a `pk` or `id` which you can use as a replacement for the translated version. The code would look something like this:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Msg(models.Model):
   msgContents = models.TextField()
   sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   date_sent = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   
   def __str__(self):
      return '<What you want the Django admin page to use as the title>' # Example: return f'{self.sender} - {self.pk}'
```

I'm not exactly sure if this will help, but it's commonly used code for a message / posting system.